# How to install Ubuntu on an old Toshiba qosmio x300 laptop

Tags: system-installation

I have a working Toshiba Qosmio x300 laptop.  But, I can't find the Vista recovery disk for it, even can't find a legit one to buy.

So, I've decided to repurpose it to use Ubuntu.   I saw posts on the Toshiba X770 in this forum, but it does say anything about how to get the laptop installed with Ubuntu.

Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: Why would installing Ubuntu on your device be any different than any other device? You've not given us any details about the actual hardware your system contains... As long as the laptop doesn't have a 32-bit CPU, you should be fine to follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). It you need additional help after following the tutorial, please reference the tutorial when asking. We generally cannot solve hypothetical problems, so if you have an actual problem, please ask and provide details about the actual problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say you have "no disk drives".   You will need a flash drive to create Ubuntu installation media. You will also need some kind of hard drive on the laptop. You cannot install Ubuntu if the laptop does not have a hard drive.

Comment: With an older system, you may want a lighter weight flavor. Full Ubuntu is now really for more recent systems with better specs. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie I was able to install Kubuntu in my old 2006  XP system but Ubuntu would not even install.

Comment: Please add the specifications of your laptop. You may want to use lightweight operating systems like [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/) or [antiX](https://antixlinux.com/download/) instead of regular Ubuntu.

Comment: I understand that Toshiba qosmio x300 laptop is Intel and Raspberry is ARM. I am using Ubuntu Mate 22.04 for RPi, sometimes the graphics breaks up a bit, I think I preferred 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)